# Track paid/free users through Flurry Analytics

Tags: android, flurry

I have integrated Flurry Analytics in my Android app. Its a free app with in-app purchasing. After looking at the statistics for two weeks, I now have a count of the unique users and active users during last week.
Now, I want to extract the user ID (Gmail IDs) of my users and keep track free and paid users.

I want output like this:

---

User ID | Purchase Status

xyz@gmail.com | Free

axz@gmail.com | Free

syz@gmail.com | Paid

xew@gmail.com | Paid

---

Of course, the output will change if users purchase the in-app.
What is the best way to achieve this? Shall I declare events?
I read somewhere that I can't download all event logs in Flurry in one-go. I have to manually download each page. This is quite frustrating.
Please help.

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: and about Flurry ? what is your problem ?

Comment: i have extracted the gmail id, set the gmail id by calling FlurryAgent.setUserId(gmailid)
i have created an event (purchase_status), with two parameters 'Free' and 'Paid'.
the value of this event depends on whether the user has purchased any in-app.
each time the flurry session starts, i am logging this event.
but now, as i told earlier, i have a huge list of event logs which i am only able to download per page.
i want to download all event logs which unfortunately flurry doesn't provide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use events to track in-app purchases. Are you planning to log user ID in Flurry ?
Once you implement events in in-app purchases, please reach out to support@flurry.com with the API key of App in question and we will try to find a work around for the same.

Thanks